# how to add a delay between two frame animations in android studio?

Tags: android, animation

I have used for 2 image-views for the animations, and i want a delay between these two animations.
following is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        faded();
        faded2();
    }
    public void faded()
    {
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fade);
        AnimationDrawable ani=(AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
        ani.start();
    }
    public void faded2()
    {
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fade2);
        AnimationDrawable ani=(AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
        ani.start();
    }
}

the above code starts both the animation at same time.
what should i do in order to get a delay between these two?
```

what changes should i do to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to fade in the ImageViews, you can use

```
//Initially set the alpha to 0 so we can't see it
img1.setAlpha(0.0f);
img2.setAlpha(0.0f);

//Then call the animate() on them. Note the startDelay for the second.
img1.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(300).start();
img2.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(300).setStartDelay(200).start();
```

Comment: what are img1 and img2 here?

Comment: Your imageViews. Respectively **ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);** and **ImageView img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);** from your code